# Upper bounding the tail probability of a sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is $P(X + Y > 3) \leq P(X > 2) + P(Y > 1)$? All I've come up with is that $\{X > 2\} \subseteq \{X > 3\}$ and $\{Y > 1\}\subseteq \{Y > 3\}$. (And tail bounds i.e. Markov's and Chebyshev's inequalities seem inappropriate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from a union bound: $\{X+Y > 3\} \subset \{X > 2\} \cup \{Y > 1\}$ hence $P(X+Y>3) \leq P(X>2 \ \text{or}\  Y>1) \leq P(X>2) + P(Y>1)$.